# VSCode React/Redux snippets don't work in .jsx files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, code-snippets, vscode-tasks

In one instant my React/Redux snippets broke in .jsx files [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbBMV.png).
Everything was working before.

In .js everything is working correctly
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqta1.png).

Reading the forums, I came across a similar problem, the solution to which was to put a minus prefix before starting to enter the snippet and it worked
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbglT.png).

The problem is that after opening the snippet, the minus remains in front of it [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz8Ar.png).

Please help me expand the snippet without the minus prefix in .jsx files.

Update:

When i write only one character it's still work too [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQxay.png).
As soon as i enter the second character, all snippets disappear and in select menu they are missing too [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5PR3.png).

Comment: Possibly related: [Visual Studio Code's recent update is disrupting autocompletion](/q/75340072)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with typescript -- worked in .ts files, but not .tsx files.  Fixed the issue and it works as expected now.

Try the following:

1. Go into your snippet file (.json) of interest, copy the entire file into your clipboard

   - Cmd+P > ">Snippets: Configure User Snippets" > *click on your snippets file*
2. Create a new snippet file

   - Cmd+P > ">Snippets: Configure User Snippets" > New Global Snippets File > javascriptreact (enter that for your file name)
3. Paste your old snippet from your clipboard into the new snippet file
4. See if that works out-of-the-box now.
5. If not, add `"scope": "javascriptreact,javascript",` to each of your snippets (e.g. right before "prefix" after the opening bracket)

```
    "comment": {
        "scope": "javascriptreact,javascript",
        "prefix": "comm",
        "body": [
            "{/* ${1:} */}"
        ],
        "description": "comment"
    },
```

I think that should solve it.  (If looking for the answer for TypeScript, do the same steps, but replace every instance of 'javascript' with 'typescript')

On the .js/.ts files, you'll now have duplicates of your snippets, so you'll want to find your old snippets file (.json) and delete it.

*Note:  I tried just adding the "scope" line to my already existing snippets file, but I was getting some sort of linting error saying it wasn't allowed, so I just created a new file following the above steps and there error was no longer present.*